# Facebook APP token from a "placebo" APP

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, client-side

I KNOW that expose your facebook app token is not a safe approach. But I would like to understand the real risks around it since I’ve never used the facebook API in a deep way then I may not have the same view as a person who uses it deeply.

I could not find many details about what could be done with the token in hands…

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/

> Because it requires you to include your App Secret you should not
>   attempt to make this call client-side as that would expose this secret
>   to all your app users. It is important that your App Secret is never
>   shared with anyone. For this reason, this call should be performed
>   server-side

So, supposing I creates an APP just to use the token in a static way(copy and paste in any call), nothing else. What I call a “placebo”(Couldn’t find a better word) app.

- No confidential data;
- Not even public data;
- The APP won't connect to anything;
- Won't request any data from any user;
- Won't keep any data at all.

The facebook APP that I'm using for tests is not even available for all users.
- **"Not available to all users because your app is not live"**
- **"This app is in development mode"**

It’s just a Facebook APP created to generate a APP token just once and keep using it.

What real damages this token could cause?

Why this question is important for me. Because the approach of my APP is to not have server side dependency. It’s more about the proposal of the business model. An independent only client-side app would bring many benefits for me.

I hope the question can be productive in somehow.

Comment: Even if your app do not ask for any permissions and do not collect data, anyone with your secret token can act as your application name. That mean they can publish using your name and application identity.

Comment: Initially it doesn't look like a big problem, since the APP wouldn't be related to any name or any brand. The name could be any nonsense name. To use this app's token in a dodgy way would be the same that creates your own "placebo" app with no real value. What do you think?

Comment: Also, the app access token allows changing of quite a couple of app settings, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application#Updating // Embedding the app access token/app secret in client-side code is something you should __never__ do. If you want a purely client-side app, then you should let users log in to it, so that you can use their user access token for any API requests that require one.

Comment: @CBroe That's a very good point.

Comment: @CBroe Could the APP block such changes on app settings?

Comment: Even if it could, a lot of other operations that the app access token allows would still be possible. The app access token does not belong in client-side code, period.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Yes, there's a way to block it. This option on your app: "Allow API Access to App Settings
Set to No to prevent changes to app settings through API calls". This option is on advanced tab. I understand your concern but my goal here is to understand the details :) Thnaks